# How to decrypt password in android?

Tags: android, passwords, accessibility, password-protection, accessibilityservice

i am working on one project which Uses `AccessibilityService` class of android.

Getting Password through **`AccessibillityService ( TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED )`** .

But Password is in form of dots **`...........`** .

How to convert these dots to text string?

or

is there is any possible decryption solution ?

Thanks

Comment: i doubt you could do this, it doesn't seem very secure to be able to retrieve passwords through the accessibility service, but i could be wrong :)

Answer (score -2):

- Create a Key Object, using the KeyGenerator, for the DESede
  algorithm.
- Create a Cipher that implements the DESede transformation, with the
  `getInstance(String algorithm)` API method.

Here is code:-

```
public class Main {

    static String algorithm = "DESede";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Key symKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);

        byte[] encryptionBytes = encryptF("texttoencrypt", symKey, c);

        System.out.println("Decrypted: " + decryptF(encryptionBytes, symKey, c));
    }

    private static byte[] encryptF(String input, Key pkey, Cipher c) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException,

            IllegalBlockSizeException {

        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pkey);

        byte[] inputBytes = input.getBytes();

        return c.doFinal(inputBytes);
    }

    private static String decryptF(byte[] encryptionBytes, Key pkey, Cipher c) throws InvalidKeyException,

            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {

        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pkey);

        byte[] decrypt = c.doFinal(encryptionBytes);

        String decrypted = new String(decrypt);

        return decrypted;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for anwering. in decrypt method,       what pkey paramenets represents ?

Comment: i mean which we want to decrypt where to pass it ?